# How to make this query using eloquent laravel 5.3

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.3

How to make below query using eloquent in laravel 5.3

```
SELECT * 
FROM `CONTACTS` 
WHERE CONCAT(`title`, '', `fullname`, ' ', `phone`, ' ', `email`) LIKE '%search%' 
    AND `status` = 'Active' 
    AND `statusby` = 'username'
```

I have tried this but it is not working

```
Contact::select()
        ->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`title`, '', `fullname`, ' ', `phone`, ' ', `email`) LIKE '%search%' 
                    AND `status` = 'Active' AND `statusby` = 'username'"))
        ->get();
```

Comment: Try DB::table('Contact')->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(`title`, '', `fullname`, ' ', `phone`, ' ', `email`) LIKE '%search%' 
                    AND `status` = 'Active' AND `statusby` = 'username'"))
        ->get();